# Emacs -- how to delete overlays (in the form of a list)

Tags: emacs, elisp

I have about 20 overlays that are marked differently with a `t` -- e.g., `'ov-one`; `'ov-two`; `'ov-three`.  I'm looking for some assistance please to delete an entire list of overlays, instead of having a different `mapc` entry for each overlay.  The current method is as follows:

```
(defun delete-the-overlays ()

  (mapc #'(lambda (o) (when (overlay-get o 'ov-one)
    (delete-overlay o))) (overlays-in (window-start) (window-end)))

  (mapc #'(lambda (o) (when (overlay-get o 'ov-two)
    (delete-overlay o))) (overlays-in (window-start) (window-end)))

  (mapc #'(lambda (o) (when (overlay-get o 'ov-three)
    (delete-overlay o))) (overlays-in (window-start) (window-end))) )
```

It would be cleaner to have a variable list and mapcar / dolist through it, but I haven't found any examples.

```
(defvar list-of-overlays '(ov-one ov-two ov-three))
```

Comment: I don't speak emacs lisp, but what's stopping you from writing the appropriate map function? In very simple Scheme, it might look something like `(define (iter f l) (if (null? l) l (begin (f (car l)) (iter f (cdr l))))`, and you can presumably do something similar in emacs lisp.

Comment: That said, you may want to look into the `do` form, which is likely even available in emacs lisp, although I'm not sure of that. emacs lisp is old and rather hairy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple way to accomplish what (I think) you want is to add an additional overlay property, e.g., `my-overlay`, to each of the set of overlays.  Then you need test only for that property, since all of them will have it.  No need to test each overlay separately for a different property.

E.g., a given overlay would have, say, property `ov-two`, but it would also have property `my-overlay`.  Another overlay would have, say, property `ov-three`, but it too would also have property `my-overlay`.

This is a pretty standard approach, IMO.

Note that if you do this you do not also need to keep a separate list of your overlays. (But nothing precludes you from doing that also.) Just as creating a list is one way to record a set, so is putting properties on an object a way to record a set: namely, the objects that have that property.

Answer (score 1):

How 'bout

```
(defun delete-the-overlays ()
  (dolist (o (overlays-in (window-start) (window-end)))
    (when (or (overlay-get o 'ov-one)
              (overlay-get o 'ov-two)
              (overlay-get o 'ov-three))
      (delete-overlay o))))
```

Comment: Is it possible to nest another dolist or mapcar / mapc inside and have a separate list of overlays -- e.g., `(defvar list-of-overlays '(ov-one ov-two ov-three))`?  In addition to using a list of overlays, I'm hoping to delete them all to the extent they exist.

Comment: Of course.  Note that your `list-of-overlays` is not a list of *overlays* but a list of (overlay) *properties*.

Comment: Thank you for teaching me the distinction between *objects* and *properties*.  :)